How can I set up Flask server featuring github codespaces?
I'm just programming an application that uses this kind of language, and I need to know how to use it via GitHub Codespaces. I haven't tried it already, but I'm eager to learn. Could you provide a detailed guide or steps on how to set up and use GitHub Codespaces for my project? This will help me ensure that my development environment is consistent and efficient, especially when collaborating with others. Any tips on best practices or common pitfalls to avoid would also be greatly appreciated. Thank you for your assistance!

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
